# How to rotate a QPushButton?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qpainter

I would like---with Python and Qt4---to rotate a [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html) (or at least its text) so it can stand vertically. I've seen [some documentation online](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_draw_vertical_text.3F), but I couldn't make much sense out of it---it's in C and I'm C-illiterate.

From what I read though, one needs to re-implement the [paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpaintevent.html) handler, instantiate and rotate a QPainter(). What I can't figure out however is how to do this for the one QString or QPushButton I need only. I assumed the QPaintEvent would have a "sender" attribute, like signals do, but it hasn't. All I can seem to get from this event is a QRect or QRegion.

How can I find out the event specific to my button or its label?
Or, because that's the question really, how to rotate a QPushButton?

Mru, here below suggested [some C++ example](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11590-vertical-pushbutton-text?highlight=OrientationButton), which reimplements the QPushButton completely. Since I have no clue about C++ and since I don't really need a full reimplementation, I've tried to reimplement the `painEvent()` handler in Python, based on that example.

Here is what I have translated, but it does not work :\

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys



class RotatedButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent, orientation = "west"):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, text, parent)
        self.orientation = orientation

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        if self.orientation == 'west':
            painter.rotate(90)
        elif self.orientation == 'east':
            painter.rotate(270)
        else:
            raise TypeError
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, self.getSyleOptions())


    def getSyleOptions(self):

        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        options.initFrom(self)        
        size = options.rect.size()
        size.transpose()
        options.rect.setSize(size)
        options.features = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.None
        options.text = self.text()
        options.icon = self.icon()
        options.iconSize = self.iconSize()
        return options


class Main(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.count = 0
        self.application = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = RotatedButton("Hello", self, orientation="west")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    application.main = Main()
    application.main.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=OrientationButton this is c++ code but should be easily transferable to python

Comment: @mru: nice one thanks. It's a very complete doc, too bad it's in C++ :)
However I understand I should reimplement the QPushButton's painEvent() handler. Which I think would be enough for my purpose. Let's see how far I can go.

Comment: @mru: do you understand the lines `QStyleOptionButton opt; opt.initFrom(this);`? What's the initFrom() doing?

Comment: see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleoption.html#initFrom

Comment: aaah! :) I thought it was some C++ thing.

Comment: you can also use the pyqt documentation but this documentation had a higher google rank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class RotatedButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent, orientation = "west"):
        super(RotatedButton,self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.orientation = orientation

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.rotate(90)
        painter.translate(0, -1 * self.width());
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, self.getSyleOptions())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).minimumSizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).sizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def getSyleOptions(self):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        options.initFrom(self)
        size = options.rect.size()
        size.transpose()
        options.rect.setSize(size)
        options.features = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.None
        if self.isFlat():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.Flat
        if self.menu():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.HasMenu
        if self.autoDefault() or self.isDefault():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.AutoDefaultButton
        if self.isDefault():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.DefaultButton
        if self.isDown() or (self.menu() and self.menu().isVisible()):
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Sunken
        if self.isChecked():
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_On
        if not self.isFlat() and not self.isDown():
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Raised

        options.text = self.text()
        options.icon = self.icon()
        options.iconSize = self.iconSize()
        return options


class Main(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.application = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = RotatedButton("Hello", self, orientation="west")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application.main = Main()
    application.main.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: It works thanks :) Now there few points I don't really understand. For instance why use `size = super(RotatedButton, self).minimumSizeHint()` and again for `sizeHint()`? I never use `super()`, do you make the button take the size of its ancestor?
The `painter.translate()` flips the button, isn't it as easy to rotate it 270°?

Comment: super calls the parent class, see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super sizeHint as well as minimuSizeHint are AFAIK only used for layout stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this code working for both "east" and "west" orientation arguments you should use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class RotatedButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent, orientation = "west"):
        super(RotatedButton,self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.orientation = orientation

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        if self.orientation == "east":
            painter.rotate(270)
            painter.translate(-1 * self.height(), 0);
        if self.orientation == "west":
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(0, -1 * self.width());
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, self.getSyleOptions())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).minimumSizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).sizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def getSyleOptions(self):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        options.initFrom(self)
        size = options.rect.size()
        size.transpose()
        options.rect.setSize(size)
        options.features = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.None
        if self.isFlat():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.Flat
        if self.menu():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.HasMenu
        if self.autoDefault() or self.isDefault():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.AutoDefaultButton
        if self.isDefault():
            options.features |= QtGui.QStyleOptionButton.DefaultButton
        if self.isDown() or (self.menu() and self.menu().isVisible()):
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Sunken
        if self.isChecked():
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_On
        if not self.isFlat() and not self.isDown():
            options.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Raised

        options.text = self.text()
        options.icon = self.icon()
        options.iconSize = self.iconSize()
        return options


class Main(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.application = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = RotatedButton("Hello", self, orientation="west")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application.main = Main()
    application.main.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few years after the original post but this works if you just want text to be vertical instead of horizontal. Use QTextDocument and some HTML. Add

```
<br>
```

after each letter.

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml("<p align=center><font>B<br>u<br>t<br>t<br>o<br>n</font></p>");
doc.setTextWidth(doc.size().width());

QPixmap pixmap(doc.size().width(), doc.size().height());
pixmap.fill( Qt::transparent );
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
doc.drawContents(&painter);

QPushButton button;
button->setIconSize(pixmap.size());
button->setIcon(pixmap);
```