# How to rotate a polygon on a QGraphicsScene at pyqt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

On the question [PyQT: Rotate a QLabel so that it's positioned diagonally instead of horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757246/pyqt-rotate-a-qlabel-so-that-its-positioned-diagonally-instead-of-horizontally), they are rotating the polygon using build-in methods of `QPainter`:

```
class MyLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.translate(20, 100)
        painter.rotate(-90)
        painter.drawText(0, 0, "hellos")
        painter.end()
```

However on my code I am inside a `QGraphicsScene` which seem to have have this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyFrame(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    """
        Python PyQt: How can I move my widgets on the window with mouse?
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213391
    """
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( MyFrame, self ).__init__( parent )

        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene( scene )
        self.resize( 400, 240 )

        # http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpen.html
        pencil = QtGui.QPen( QtCore.Qt.black, 2)
        pencil.setStyle( QtCore.Qt.SolidLine )

        polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF( [QtCore.QPointF( 250, 100 ), \
                QtCore.QPointF( 400, 250 ), QtCore.QPointF( 200, 150 ) ] )

        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtGui.QColor( 125, 125, 125, 125 ) )
        scene.addPolygon( polygon, pencil, brush )

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = QtGui.QApplication( [] )
    f = MyFrame()
    f.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How could I call on this scenario something like on the other question using the `QGraphicsScene`?

```
polygon.translate(20, 100)
polygon.rotate(-90)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use an object of class `QTransform`, this one has the capacity to implement many transformations. The `addPolygon` function returns the item, and we use this item to apply the transformation.

```
p = scene.addPolygon(polygon, pencil, brush)

transform = QtGui.QTransform()
transform.translate(20, 100)
transform.rotate(-90)

p.setTransform(transform)
```

**before:**

[image]

**after:**

[image]

Comment: where do the values in transform.translate() come from? (20,100)

Comment: @usario30032021 The item if transformation is in a certain position in the scene and then you move it (20, 100). It is not a value that depends on something but that value was chosen by the OP.